# How to create Login by consuming Rest Webservice?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am very new to visual studio, i have been asked to develop a ios application in xamarin. I want to know how to login using rest service and validate whether the user is already in the database or not. i have no idea, please help a fellow programmer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your question is too broad to answer, try to be specific problem which your are facing.

Comment: Please do you research on that beforehand

Comment: Hi @dhilmathy, i have a rest service which contains all the user credentials. but i dont know how to consume the rest service and validate the user.

Comment: there are literally thousands of example of using REST here on SO and elsewhere on the web.

Comment: I have an example using asp.net with sql user accounts if that's your server side tech